# vibrant.js get image data

Tags: javascript, image

I was trying this libarary call vibrant.js where we can get color samples of the images. I have sucessfully implemented for one set of images. When i trying to do the same for another set of images error is popping. I can't figure it out what's wrong.
 I am geting one of the following error

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The source height is 0.
```

or

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getHex' of undefined
```

From this i thought it's something wrong in image loading. so i have use this following codes to figure out what happening.

```
                var img = new Image($(this)); // creating image element

img.onload = function() { // trigger if the image was loaded
    console.log($(this).attr('src') + ' - done!');
}

img.onerror = function() { // trigger if the image wasn't loaded
    console.log($(this).attr('src') + ' - error!');
}

img.onAbort = function() { // trigger if the image load was abort
    console.log($(this).attr('src') + ' - abort!');
}
```

For this, nothing appears in the console. But if i just use those code without any functions i am able to see the URL in the log. 
 I have been trying this for hours. Can any one have any suggestions or any idea where i am gone wrong.
**Note: all functions are called inside the `$(window).load`**

Answer (score 0):

[`Image()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) does not expect a jQuery object as first parameter. Expected parameters are `width` and `height` as numbers; e.g., `new Image(100, 100)`